# Read a File in Java8 which is not under src folder

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Java and I am trying to read a file from `./resources/filter.txt`.
I am have written the following function to read the files, so far I am able to read this filter.txt from `./src/test/resources/filter.txt`

```
String loadhere(String filePath) {

    URI resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath).toURI();
    Path path = Paths.get(resource);
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return content;

  }
```

But this throws Null Pointer exception as `.getResouces(filePath)` is returning null.
After some research I tried to use `.getResourceAsStream()` But it also throws the same error for me.
Any Idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why your file is located there?

Comment: @Jens The Usecase is such that some files need to be stored at ./resources

Comment: Can you add the path to the classpath?

Comment: This question has been asked [literally] thousands of times already. Enter the following into the search box at the top of this Web page: **[java] getResource**.  Having said that, the _simplest_ way to fix your code, is to put file `filter.txt` into the same directory as the compiled class file that contains method `loadhere` and use the following code (in method `loadhere`): `URI resource = getClass().getResource("filter.txt").toURI();`

Comment: @Abra I know this solution to move the file would work but this file cannot be moved to the same location .

Comment: filePath needs to be `"filter.txt"`.  Nothing else.  (The argument passed to getResource and getResourceAsStream is a relative URL, not a filename.)  Be aware that using Path means your program will not work if it is built as a .jar file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the straight foward aproach for your use-case. Pass file name `filter.txt` to the method.

```
String loadhere(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("src","test","resources",fileName);
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return content;
}
```